# How to get the next month in PHP?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm currently using the following code to calculate the next month:

```
$nextMonth = date("m",strtotime("+1 months"));
```

If the current date is March 31 (03), this code gives me "05" which is actually 2 months away from the current date. I would like it to return April (04) instead.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: PHP date functions does not do this very well. You will have to do the calculation yourself or might be able to find a library that does this.

Comment: I would suggest to try ZF Date class. http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about trying this:

```
$d = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
$d->modify( 'first day of next month' );
echo $d->format( 'F' ), "\n";
```

Dins