# PHP Date Calculation to display the next 1st June

Tags: php, date

I need to be able to calculate a date using PHP that displays the next 1st of June.  So, today is **15th April 2013** therefore I need to display **01/06/2013 (UK format)**.  If the date was **5th August 2013** I would need to display **01/06/2014**.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

John

Comment: try strtotime("next 1st June")

Comment: @HaimEvgi I don't that is implemented.

Comment: May you please supply a valid formula?

Comment: check this post..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726228/how-to-get-the-next-month-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using :

```
$now = time();
$june = strtotime("1st June");

if ($now > $june)
    echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime('+1 year', $june));
else 
    echo date("d/m/Y", $june);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

For this you can achieve by checking the present month

```
   if(date('m')>06)
   {
       $date= date('d-m-Y',strtotime("next year June 1st"));
    }
   else{
          $date= date('d-m-Y',strtotime("this year June 1st"));
    }
    echo $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new DateTime object for the current year. DateTime is the preferred way to handle dates in PHP.

If it's too early, create a new datetime object for the following year.

Finally, use 'format' to output.

```
$d = new DateTime(date('Y').'-08-05');
if ($d < new DateTime()) {
  $d = new DateTime((date('Y')+1).'-04-15');
}

echo $d->format('d/m/Y');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using this tutorial. You can define time zone and display the date as per your format.

Check this manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

clear examples are given here:

```
  <?php
      // set the default timezone to use. Available since PHP 5.1
         date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); 
         echo $today = date("d/m/y");                         // 03/10/01
   ?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. The problem I am having is grabbing the next 1st of June date more than formatting the UK date.